# node mysql variable comparison

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi i'm working on a little project at i'm stuck. What i'm trying to do is to compare mysql row with a variable to get a user steamid from the database (function winner_daily) (sry for my english :( ) . Here my code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'localhost',
  user            : 'root',
  password        : '*****',
  database        : 'bet'
});

pool.query("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE  levels >= 3 ", function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var rand = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)];

     winner_daily(rand);


});
function winner_daily(winner){

 console.log("And the winner is :",winner);
 pool.query(`SELECT steamid FROM users WHERE name = ${mysql.escape(winner)}`, function (error, row, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;

  console.log(row)
});

}
```

Comment: It's clear what you want to do, but what is the problem you are having with the code now? What happens and what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
 console.log("And the winner is :",winner);

pool.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name`=' + winner.name, function (error, row) {
      if (error) throw error;
      if(!row.length)   console.log('There is not any row'); return false;  

      console.log(row)
    });
```

you need to pass winner name in the query.

Comment: Hi thanks for your fast reply apreciated but i still got an error here : https://pastebin.com/y8giehWv

Comment: can you please send me the result of console.log("And the winner is :",winner)???? i think winner is object so you need to write winner.name instead of winner

Comment: Here what i got in the console And the winner is : RowDataPacket { name: 'thomas' }

Comment: @ThomasCogez I know that so i have updated answer bro!you need to write winner.name instead of winner

Comment: Im sorry but still got an little error ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'michel' in 'where clause'